# How to resolve "Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = The swarm does not have a leader."

Tags: docker, virtualbox, docker-swarm, docker-machine

I am trying to learn docker and swarm. I created a swarm with 3 nodes and completed an example using virtualbox and docker-machine. I  Once i restarted my machine, All nodes shown as stopped. I started all nodes using

```
docker-machine start node1 node2 node3
```

All node started but still I am not able to list nodes even on master node and getting below error:

```
docker@node1:~$ docker node ls                                                                                                               
Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = The swarm does not have a leader. It's possible that too few managers are online. Make sure more than half of the managers are online.
```

Also the docker state on node1 (master) is pending.

```
Swarm: pending
  NodeID: c93hv5pixlfiei7q9qneuiuen
  Error: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = The swarm does not have a leader. It's possible that too few managers are online. Make sure more than half of the managers are online.
```

I am getting this error every time i restarted my machine.This is causing me to setup everything from start each time.

Is there anyway I can avoid setting up cluster again and again.

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

please check the firewall on linux:

If you want to promote some NODE as manager, so you please check the port=2377 is accepting request on particular node. Then only Node work as manager. Otherwise  you will get an error like below :

Error response from daemon: rpc error: code = Unknown desc = The swarm does not have a leader. It's possible that too few managers are online. Make sure more than half of the managers are online.

Solution : Add port number 2377 in firewall.

## firewall-cmd --zone=public --add-port=2377/tcp --permanent

success

## firewall-cmd --reload

success

Answer (score 0):

You must include the docker service start somewhere in your boot config.

Answer (score 0):

### Preventing

`demote` the node you are going to "switch off"/leave swarm

```sh
# find node id
$ docker node ls
ID                            HOSTNAME            STATUS    AVAILABILITY   MANAGER STATUS   ENGINE VERSION
o1iz67ehuenfzbyg2gjxayaee     hostA               Ready     Active         Reachable        20.10.6
fic857lrupfemxqie5rvq63yt *   hostB               Ready     Active         Leader           20.10.6

$ docker node demote o1iz67ehuenfzbyg2gjxayaee
Manager o1iz67ehuenfzbyg2gjxayaee demoted in the swarm.

# now on, the node can safely leave the swarm
$ docker swarm leave --force
```

### Reacting

#### Restart if there are no healthy nodes.

Start >> stop Docker engine (NOT `restart`) and init Swarm again. Validate firewall ruleset afterwards as Docker overwrites it.

```sh
$ systemctl stop docker
$ systemctl start docker
```

#### Drain left node if there is healthy manager node.

Reference https://cynici.wordpress.com/2018/05/31/docker-info-rpc-error-on-manager-node/